# How to show alert message on jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery now a days, I have one jquery variable: var test = true; If I click this variable, I can show this message in my four s, But I need to display one alert message for fifth time and or above time to not to display this value. How can I achieve this ?

```
if(test){
<div id="1">test</div>
<div id="2">test</div>
<div id="3">test</div>
<div id="4">test</div> 
<div id="5">test</div>
<div id="6">test</div>
}
```

Comment: is this your html?something is wrong with it.also pls add js

Comment: what is this ? correct your post

Comment: Actually I have this scenario, but I cannot post it exactly as it involves many things in my application, my requirement is I need to display one alert message on showing of any variable message from fifth time on wards ! Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You can't click on a variable... I think you might want to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Past a jsfiddle so we can have exact idea about the issue

Comment: I have created one dummy code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/5az2yr19/1/ , How can show the alert message from fifth time onwards here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/5az2yr19/3/).

Use a count variable to make this working! Hope this will help you.

**JS**

```
var count = 0;
$("#test").click(function(){
    var test = true;
    count++;
    if(count >= 5) {
        if(test){
            alert("test: "+test);
        }
    }
});
```